# Passing an array of integer in POST body in a DELETE method

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, ajax

I don't know but this seems ambiguous to me. I'm trying to make a DELETE request, applied on multiple objects, referenced with their IDs (the ones in the array).

This is my controller :

```
    [HttpDelete]
    public void RemoveRoomWithDevices([FromUri]int roomId, [FromBody] int[] userDevicesId)
    { //code
    }
```

This is the JS :

```
    function DeleteRoomWithDevices(RoomID, FloorId, userDevicesID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Room/RemoveRoomWithDevices?RoomId=" + RoomID,
        type: "DELETE",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            userDevicesId: userDevicesID
        },
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {//success}
    });
```

Here, in the POST column, the array is not passed (I'm debugging with firebug). When I replace the type with `type: "POST"` I am able to see the array but I can't execute the delete query.

What do you suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that `DELETE` should not contain request body. It's not dissallowed in the spec (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) but I've read something in past that controller just ignores it. Why you cant execute delete query in POST?  What's more, you can pass and array as URL - if such an array is not big.

Comment: Yes, well when I did it I got this error {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}

Comment: Nice discussion about DELETE body: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323716/restful-alternatives-to-delete-request-body. How to pass array parameter in GET (and DELETE): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-of-integers-to-a-asp-net-web-api-rest-service

Comment: @Sahar Ch changing type `DELETE` to `POST` is not enough - you should change action attribute from `HttpDelete` to `HttpPost` :)

Comment: Ah yesss! How did I miss that! I'll give it a try thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pass both parameters with data and their name should match parameters of the method:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/api/Room/RemoveRoomWithDevices",
        type: "DELETE",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            roomId: RoomID,
            userDevicesId: userDevicesID
        },
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {//success}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

"The spec does not explicitly forbid or discourage http body"
[Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

For my own opinion delete request shouldn't contain any body as well as have to point exactly one resource for deletion (/cars for all collection /cars/{id} for particular entity)
Batch deletion is not obvious topic you can look at the following topic about it

[Patterns for handling batch operations in REST web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511281/patterns-for-handling-batch-operations-in-rest-web-services)