# Angular JS Restangular: How to remove() multiple records using array of ids as request body?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, restangular

The Restangular.remove() function sends the request object as query params(EXAMPLE: /users?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3) instead of send these ids as a body params(JSON format)

**Example Code:**

> ```
> $scope.users = {};
> $scope.myIds = ['1','2','3'];
> $scope.users.ids = $scope.myIds;
> var baseUsers = Restangular.all('users');
> baseUsers.remove($scope.users).then(function(data){
> console.log("Rsp Data :", data);
> };
> ```

How to sending this array of ids **$scope.users** as a request body..?

Comment: have you tried the custom methods from [link]http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/restangular.html, author.customPOST({body: "Ari's Bio"}, // post body
  "biography",  // route
  {},           // custom params
  {});          // custom headers

Comment: HTTP DELETE requests normally don't have a request body. DELETE requests normally come in the form of DELETE /user/5 or with a batch of deletes something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511281/patterns-for-handling-batch-operations-in-rest-web-services