# WCF or Web Api for WPF

Tags: wpf, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I'm a noob so please I hope you can help me and understand that maybe my question is dummy or not-well oriented.

In Visual Studio, I have a Web Api consumed from a MVC App (which applies CRUD methods). Now I need a WPF Application just for read the information (not create, not update, not delete).

My question: Can I use the same Web Api project or I need add a WCF project???? I don't know if is some difference.

NOTE: I have to pass thousands of records. I don't know if this matters or not. Again, I'm noob.

Comment: Please elaborate on "can I use". You can consume any web service from WPF, granted you've got the right libraries. Just search for "C# consume WebAPI" for some pointers.

Comment: The below gives an idea about the points to be considered while choosing between Web API and WCF. If your get operation is not REST based then you can consider implementing the service using WCF. As @CodeCaster mentioned you can also use WebAPI with WPF. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You should definitely reuse the same Web API project (it is already done!). If performance is a concern because of the thousands records requirement, then maybe using WCF could alleviate that by using some transport other than HTTP. You would have to set goals and do some benchmarking to decide, I guess.

Comment: With thousands of records, you'll want to look at modifying your Web API REST service to support performing batch operations.  [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511281/patterns-for-handling-batch-operations-in-rest-web-services) more on that topic.